# Do sample estimators have to satisfy a relationship that is satisfied by the population regressors?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, unbiased-estimator

Say in  case of a standard CLRM ( classical linear regression model ) we are aware that the population estimaotrs $\beta_1$ , $\beta_2$ etc. satisfy the following relation that

$f(\beta_1$,$\beta_2$,$\beta_3$ ...) = 0 $

Does this imply that the standard CLRM sample estimators i.e. $\beta'$ ,$\beta_2'$ etc. will follow the same relationship , i.e.

$f( \beta_1'$,$\beta_2'$ ...) = 0 $

I could deduce that in case of simple linear relationships we could expect this to be the case for simple linear realtionship by taking expectation and using the property that $E(\beta_1'+\beta_2' +....)$ = $E(\beta_1') + E(\beta_2') +...$

But I am not so sure if I could follow the same procedure with a more general case.

Comment: As @eric_kernfeld mentions, you can impose that condition in the estimation phase. If it's a linear restriction, it's a fairly standard, well documented etc... case. A term to lookup/Google for may be "over-identifying restriction."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, your sample estimates will not be zero. But, they will *converge* to zero as you get more data. Details follow.

Anyone is welcome to refine the convergence claims that I make here, but:

Suppose your model says $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ with $X$ being a fixed design matrix of full column rank and $\epsilon$ being i.i.d. Gaussian noise. Suppose we have $n$ samples. Then the MLE for $\beta$ is $$\hat \beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TX\beta + (X^TX)^{-1}X^TX\epsilon = \beta + (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon $$, and it converges to the true value under "reasonable" asymptotic scenarios. You are correct that the estimates need not satisfy the same constraints that govern the true parameters -- to see this, draw an iid standard Normal sample and verify that the mean differs from zero. The closest claims I could justify:

- If $f$ is linear, then $E[f(\hat \beta)]$ is zero in expectation, as you noticed.
- If $f$ is continuous, then $f(\hat \beta)$ converges to zero in probability.
- If $f$ is twice differentiable with gradient of $\nabla f(\beta) = D$, then $f(\hat \beta)$ converges to zero and the distance from zero has a variance of approximately $D^T(X^TX)^{-1}D$ (via the delta method). Footnote: the limiting variance usually has a factor of $1/n$; in my case, that's buried inside the $(X^TX)^{-1}$. For instance, if we are estimating the mean, then $X$ is a column of ones and $(X^TX)^{-1} = 1/n$.

If you really need those constraints, you should try to impose them, or if you just kinda want them, perhaps you could add a penalty such as $-\lambda f^2(\beta)$ to your likelihood.

**EDIT: more info on convergence in probability**

We are dealing with convergence in probability, so I want to show that for every $q_0, \epsilon > 0$, there exists a sample size such that $P(|f(\hat \beta) - f(\beta)| > \epsilon) < q_0$. My tools of choice: continuity and convergence in probability of $\hat \beta$.

Suppose $\hat \beta$ converges to $\beta$ in probability. That means for every $p_0, \delta > 0$, there exists a sample size such that $P(||\hat \beta - \beta|| > \delta) < p_0$. This is a lot like what I want to show: if I choose $p_0=q_0$, then I just need to choose $\delta$ such that the "bad behavior in $f$" event, $|f(\hat \beta) - f(\beta)| > \epsilon$, is contained in the "bad behavior in $\hat \beta$" event. Fortunately, $f$ is continuous, so for any $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that $|f(\hat \beta) - f(\beta)| < \epsilon$ whenever  $||\beta - \beta|| < \delta$. Please forgive sloppiness in strict/weak inequalities.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how $f(\beta^)$ converges to zero in case f is continuos function ?

Comment: Yup -- edited it with that info.